# I can't uninstall and reinstall epic games

Tags: hard-drive

To change partition setting, I deleted my E Drive. And I can't access any app in it, so i hve to uninstall them. When I press uninstall, it says invalid E Drive. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

If the supplied uninstaller cannot uninstall the product,
use a third-party uninstaller such as
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).

Revo will call the uninstaller for the application, which will fail,
then clean up after it, including files and registry items.